# can we write to a word file using c?

Tags: c, file, docx

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fs,*ft;
    char ch;
    fs=fopen("main.c","r");
    if(fs==NULL)
    {
        printf("can not open source file\n");
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    ft=fopen("demo.docx","w");
    if(ft==NULL)
    {
        printf("can not open target file\n");
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        ch=fgetc(fs);
        if(ch==EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        fputc(ch,ft);
    }
    fclose(fs);
    fclose(ft);
    return 0;
}
```

Using the above code, I tried to copy the contents of `main.c` to `demo.docx`.
The program worked fine, but when I externally opened `demo.docx`, it crashed.
Is there a problem from my side, or we can not write to a `docx` file using c?

Comment: Yes you can. But did you study in great detail the [docx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docx) file format (You'll need months or years of work)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : please give me a conclusion

Comment: Here is an idea. French and English have the same alphabet (well nearly). So would an English word mean the same in French?

Comment: @RaginScallion: that would be *"omelette au fromage"* in French....

Comment: I was careful in the ordering of the languages. Normans invaded us - and we stole/they gave us some words. They are doing the reverse at this moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Word document isn't written like a normal text file, but rather written in a very specific format which you would have to follow. This can of course be done in C but I strongly would recommend against it and instead try to find some library to use or use a different language and framework. Both C#/.Net and Java have good options for working with Office documents (for Java there's [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) for example).

If you really want to waste your time you can find the specs for the Office files here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313105%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: is the same thing applicable for .txt files

Comment: @zee: no. A text file is just plain text. Any file with formatting instructions (.rtf, .doc, .docx, .odf, etc.) will need more than just plain text written to the file; there will be a specific format you need to follow.

Answer (score 3):

MS Word `*.docx` files are not normal text files and you need a specialized library to access such files such as http://libopc.codeplex.com/.